# Is there any way I can print multiple elements each of an array twice on separate lines?

Tags: javascript

My code so far prints the whole array twice but I want to print each array element twice such that "Daudu" appears twice side by side etc and others like that on separate lines.

```
let Smart = ["Daudu", "Emma", "Skodo", "John", "Jones", "Mike", "Sierra", "Oscar", "Alpha", "Bravo"];
console.log(Smart.join('\r\n'));
console.log(Smart.join('\r\n'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that?

```js
let Smart = ["Daudu", "Emma", "Skodo", "John", "Jones", "Mike", "Sierra", "Oscar", "Alpha", "Bravo"];
Smart.forEach(element => console.log(element, element));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop

```js
const smart = ['Daudu', 'Emma', 'Skodo', 'John', 'Jones', 'Mike', 'Sierra', 'Oscar', 'Alpha', 'Bravo'];

for (const item of smart) {
    console.log(`${item}, ${item}`);
}
```

Or you can create a new array then do the same thing as above

```js
const smart = ['Daudu', 'Emma', 'Skodo', 'John', 'Jones', 'Mike', 'Sierra', 'Oscar', 'Alpha', 'Bravo'];

const newSmart = smart.map((item) => `${item}, ${item}`);

for (const item of newSmart) {
    console.log(item);
}
```